# Issue with password checking

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem with checking if a password is the same with the password confirmation. The logic is good i don't think that i have a mistake in my code.

```
      $("#pass2").keyup(function(){ 
        check_password();  
    });
       function check_password(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "register.php",
  data: {
  'pass1_check': $("#pass1").val(),
  'pass2_check': $("#pass2").val()
  },
  success : function(data){
  if(data == 'success'){

      $("#output_pass2").html('<img src="images/check.png" alt=""/>');
  $("#output_pass1").html('<img src="images/check.png" alt=""/>');


  }
      else{
   $("#output_pass2").css("color","red").html(data);
  }
  }

  });
  }
```

My problem is in this condition : if(data == 'success') 
In my output i don't have an image, i have in output "success" and not the check image

my register.php :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['pass1_check'])&& !empty($_POST['pass2_check']))
{
  if(strlen($_POST['pass1_check']) <6 || strlen($_POST['pass2_check']) <6)
  {
      echo'<br>Very short';
      exit();
  }else if($_POST['pass1_check'] == $_POST['pass2_check']){
      echo'success';
          exit();
}else{
      echo '<br> the two password are not same';
    exit();

  }
}

?>
```

the two label of password in html code :

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label  for="pass1"  class="col-sm-5 control-label">Password :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="Password" id="pass1" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Your Password " required>
         <small id="output_pass1" ></small>
    </div>


      </div>
          <div class="form-group">
   <label for="pass2"  class="col-sm-5 control-label">Confirm Your Password :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="Password" class="form-control" id="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Your Password " required>
        <small id="output_pass2"></small>
    </div>

      </div>
```

I use bootstrap 3 for design css.

Comment: What does alert(data) show you if u add it before the if statement in ur Ajax response?

Comment: Why do you have to use ajax to verify the length? In the same way, ou don't need to send this data to the server to compare if the strings are the same. Javascript can already do this.

Comment: Is this page always served via `https`?  If not, `$.ajax({...url: "register.php",...)` is sending passwords in the clear.  You should probably specify an absolute https URL just to be on the safe side.

Comment: You should really try to follow some code style guides. Try following Googles for example https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your POST Data part is not correct

UPDATE as ponted out by  Mike Samuel the following should work.
You have

```
data: {
  'pass1_check': $("#pass1").val(),
  'pass2_check': $("#pass2").val()
  },
```

As mentioned  `if(data == 'success')` is not working.

May be need to do as

```
if(data.trim() == 'success')
```

Making sure to remove all white spaces if any.

Comment: It's ok to quote keys in object constructors.  It doesn't change the semantics of the program at all.

Comment: still the same probleme when i put alert(data) before if statement i have input a good value the probleme is only in if(data == 'success') the program don't read this line :(

Comment: @MikeSamuel you are right my bad I never had used '' so at first glance it looks to em an error !!

Comment: @JohnLow as you mention you get alert(data) with some good data you may need to use trim() in if condition, check my updated answer.

Comment: Also i have the same probleme i have success on red color instead of image ( check.png)

Comment: in the PHP file give a space after echo  .... echo'success'; and alert data on sucess and see what you get, also use data.trim() == 'success' in the if condition in addition make sure no html is there on the top of your PHP file.

Comment: the probleme was solved by @Abhik Chakraborty thank you very mush